# Custom filter not working

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I am very new to Wordpress Development so this question might be silly .May be I do not understand the concept of custom filters in Wordpress . So far I have used Wordpress's own filter hooks to change values

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ffl_add_footer') ; // add footer to the blog content
```

I have just started learning about custom filters that you can code . So my understanding is you use apply_filters() to set up a filter hook to a value like below

```
apply_filters('filter_tag' , $var ) ;
```

later you hook into that filter and  use a callback function to modify the value ($var) like below

```
add_filter('filter_tag , 'callback')
```

Your callback would be like below :

```
function callback($var) {
//modify $var 
return $var

}
```

So I was testing this understanding with a code like below :

```
function callback($var){
    return ($var.'append');
}


$var = 'testing';
echo $var;
$var1 = apply_filters('custom_filter', $var);
add_filter('custom_filter' , 'callback');
echo $var1;
```

This echoes testingtesting while I was expecting testingtestingappend .   Am I understanding this wrong or is there something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your the simple nature of your example may have led to a misunderstanding of the way `appy_filters()` would operate. There is a [great article](https://wpshout.com/apply_filters-do_action/) that really explains how to use `add_filter()` and `apply_filters()` well, using very readable examples.

Basically, the problem appears to be that your code declares `add_filter()` AFTER you define it with `apply_filters()`. This is an "order of operations" error.

Perhaps this annotated version can help:

```
// declare your filter function and callback .. usually pretty close to each other.
add_filter('ex1_append_text', 'callback_appender');
function callback_appender($initial_text){
    return $initial_text.' ... whatever ...';
}

// setup basic variable, as you did
$var = 'testing';
echo $var;

// apply the filters we declared above
$modified = apply_filters('ex1_append_text',$var);
echo $modified;
```

Comment: BTW ... you are encouraged to add some unique letter combination, or abbreviation, to the beginning of filter and action names, to decrease the likelihood of collisions with other functions/plugins, etc.  So, in my example, I used 'ex1_'.  You might have used 'kno_' (taken from your screen name).

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I thought it worked the other way . However , now I have a related question . What happens when you try to hook into a filter of an existing plugin (say plugin named B) . How do I ensure my plugin's add_filter() is executed first and later B's apply_filter() is executed . The plugins seems to run in an alphabetical order . Does that mean my plugin needs to be named A ?

Comment: Properly written plugins use [wordpress hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) to set the order, and should not care about the execution order. A plugin that modifies content or display elements is building a queue which will recognize [priorities set by action hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).  If you would like me to provide sample code, start a new question regarding Plugins and Action Hooks.  I'll be happy to provide examples.  If you still want to [order plugin operations](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/)

Comment: P.S. When someone provides a response that directly answers your initial question, it is polite to mark it as the answer ... (hint .. hint) Others will return the favor, if you provide answers.

Comment: Sorry I missed marking your answer . I have started a question in SO , may be I am not understanding this right . Could you take a look into it ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708148/how-to-hook-into-filters-in-another-plugin